# spring-boot application fails to start

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I recently start to develop a web application with spring-boot, anf, following the guide in the offical site, manage to create this two files:

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <start-class>com.spring.app.Application</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

`Application.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }

}
```

but when I try run the application with `java -jar appname` i get the error: `Cannot find the main class: com.spring.app.Application. Program will exit`, and in the terminal: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/spring/app/Application`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 things to do in your pom.xml.

First change the start-class to your application class.
Second add the super-cool Spring Boot maven builder to your pom.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>beanlist</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.sample.Application</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project
```

Then use "mvn install" to create your jar.  Your code runs just fine.

Comment: Ok, I tried this modification in my pom.xml (the other files remain unchanged) but still got the same error.

Comment: Hmmm, worked great for me.  Triple check <start-class> for the right package name.  That should be your application class and not "com.spring.app.Application."

Comment: Spring boot should be able to detect the start-class itself if there is only a single class with a main method. The most important part is adding the spring-boot maven plugin.

Comment: @M.Deinum humm, I have only two classes in my project right now: the Application.java, where I place the main method, and one named HelloController. In my pom.xml I put in start-class the full path for the class (package included). I try only with the name of the class, but don't work too.

Comment: You don't need that the plugin will find the class. Just remove it... The import part is the spring boot plugin and the parent.

Comment: FWIW, you need the plugin to create an 'uber' jar with all the dependencies.  https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#use-maven  It will run without it, but the complete jar makes life easy.

Answer (score 1):

Value of the following tag should be changed to match real class with main method. Try to specify correct package and run "mvn install"

```
<start-class>com.sample.Application</start-class>
```

Comment: yes, the tag have the correct value: `com.spring.app.Application`.

Answer (score 0):

you Application is in this package:
`package com.spring.app;`

which means your Application full path should be package com.spring.app.Application and your error code said `com.spring.Application` not found.
Maybe you should check your run configuration

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error. Its got resolved by converting the project to maven in eclipse as mentioned in below image:[image]

Hope it will you. :)